# WOW.js start animation when element is 60% in screen

Tags: javascript, css

Using WOW.js, is it possible to start an animation when X% of the element is visible rather than using an offset value?

For example I have an element with a width and height of 300px, and if I set X% to 50% the animation will start when the user has scrolled enough so that 150px of element is on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked over the source code of WOW.js and it doesn't look like there's a way to specify an offset as a percentage rather than in pixels. So here's how to do it in javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("offsetme50");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var offset = elements[i].clientHeight * .5;   //.5 = 50%
        elements[i].setAttribute("data-wow-offset", offset);
    }
}
```

This code will run automatically after the page is loaded. Set `class="offsetme50"` to all the HTML elements you want.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to make it as global function rather than for certain element only? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IlijaMilovic Sure! I just edited my answer. I haven't tested it so let me know if that works.

Comment: @IlijaMilovic Was that helpful?

Comment: thanks a lot, but I dont understand. If I want it to make global which means to start animation on every element when it is showed 50% on screen than what purpose have myDiv? once again thanks!

Comment: @IlijaMilovic Ok I see what you are trying to do. I updated the code.